# Approximating derivative of numerical solution (using ode45) within event function

Tags: matlab

The issue I have is having to compute the derivative (in real time) of the solution produced by ode45 within the events function.

Some pseudo-code to explain what I'm mean is,

```matlab
function dx = myfunc(t,x,xevent)
persistent xevent
% xevent is the solution at the event
dx(1) = x(2);
dx(2) = complicated function of x(1),x(2), and xevent;
end

function [value,isterminal,direction] = myeventfcn(t,x)
position = function of x(1), x(2), and dx(2); 
isterminal = 1;
direction = 0;
end
```

I know that if I didn't need to use the solution at the event within `myfunc` I could just compute `dx=myfunc(t,x)` within my event function and use `dx(2)`, yet since `xevent` is used within `myfunc` I can't input `xevent`.

I know there is a way of inputting constant parameters within the event function, but since it's the solution at the event location, which also changes, I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

My work around to this is to approximate `dx(2)` using the solution `x`. What I wanted to know is if it will be satisfactory to just use a finite difference approximation here, using a small fixed step size relative to the step size od45 takes, which is a variable step size.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Dense output functions should be able to calculate this for free (without an $f$ call) using the analytical solution for the derivative on the interpolant (just take the $\theta$ derivative, in the common notation). This is setup in DifferentialEquations.jl as `integrator(t,Val{1})` and in Sundials with `CVodeDKy`: does MATLAB not have something similar? I would be surprised given the ease of implementation. If it has a dense output function you can call that's likely the most efficient way and should be similar order as the solution itself, or at least similar enough.

Comment: I believe there is a way to calculate the derivative using `diff` when you have the computed solution. I need to be able to approximate the derivative while ode45 is running.

Comment: Well `diff` is using the discrete values. I'm talking about the dense output function.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is such a function, albeit I'm probably not the best person to ask. I did a quick google search and found this paper which defines what a dense output is. http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~ljay/publications.dir/EACM_Dense_Output.pdf Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, and that's written by the author of the MATLAB ODE suite. If you differentiate the $y_{n+\theta}$ equation by $\theta$ you get the free interpolation for the derivative. I learned this all and implemented it in the Julia suite using papers by Shampine, so I am quite certain this must be in MATLAB somewhere, but Google searches for "dense output ODE MATLAB" and "output function ODE MATLAB" aren't showing anything of use. But that's definitely where to look.

Comment: Okay that's good to know. I'll definitely start looking around for that. As a side question, when you say $y_{n+\theta}$ you mean taking a time step of $\theta$? I'm just a little confused about the second sentence you wrote.

Comment: No, $\theta\in[0,1]$, and $y_{n+1}$ is $y(t+dt)$. Dense output gives an ODE output over the full interval as a continuous(ly differentiable) function, which is then used for event location and which has all of the tools for a free (3rd order, for ode45) derivative calculation (in $\theta$, then rescale by $dt$) if you can find it.

Comment: Oh I see. So is this essentially some sort of polynomial fit to the discrete data? Is this have anything to do with continuous extensions?

Comment: Yes, dense output functions are the continuous extensions.

Comment: Okay. So does this mean while ode45 is running, the derivative of the solution is stored somewhere or can be called within the event function?

Comment: It's definitely stored, and you can get it as the solution to `ode45`. Those I know. What I have been pointing towards is the fact that same stored information gives a free derivative calculation, Shampine has mentioned it in papers, and that in other software like in Sundials this is used to get free and correct order/tolerance derivatives. Now, I don't know for a fact if you can get it in MATLAB, (I haven't been able to find it in a Google search but don't know MATLAB well), but all those facts point to the fact that it's likely hiding in there somewhere and I just don't know where.

Comment: Okay. Thank you, I'll keep looking searching for it.